# using session save path (php)

Tags: php, session, path

I have VPS (CentOs), running few websites with sub domains, I would like to monitor my session files, Can I define separate session save path for site and its sub domains as follows?

```
session_save_path("/home/sitename1/public_html/sessionpath/");
session_save_path("/home/sitename2/public_html/sessionpath/”);
```

for subdomains

```
session_save_path("/home/sitename1/public_html/subdomainName1/sessionpath/"); 
session_save_path("/home/sitename2/public_html/subdomainName2/sessionpath/”);
```

Default path in INI is tmp which is in root dir, where I do not have rights to access.
Some of my site users losing their session files even they were active in pages. What may be reason?  Is it any background process cleaning tmp folder files?

My other settings in INI for PHP Session mechanism as follows
    session.gc_divisor 3000,
    session.gc_probability 1,
    session.gc_maxlifetime 10800,
    session.cookie_lifetime 0,

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any Linux system that forbids global access to `/tmp`, or any sysadmin that would do that anyway, but I suppose it's possible.

Session files get garbage collected based on the `gc_maxlifetime`.  In your case, it's 180 minutes or 3 hours.  This means after 3 hours of inactivity, there is a chance that a certain session will be garbage collected (i.e. removed).

If you want sessions to persist longer than that, you need another layer (e.g. a database), or you have to keep refreshing the session with JavaScript, for example.